# Angular Material Tree nested node depth

Tags: angular, tree, angular-material

I am trying to work with angular and material components.
And I have two questions:

1) How to reduce nested node depth(left offset) ? 
[Please, see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhFgT.png)

2) I apply next style for change max-height:

```
.mat-tree-node { 
  min-height: 25px;
  max-height: 25px; 
}
```

And now when I press to expand button, gray circle is drawn incorrectly. How can i fix it(change it radius)? [Please, see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzndg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to reduce left offset you can do so by css take a look [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsb9c8?file=app%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.css)

to make ripple effect work properly and because you change the `min-height` and `max-height` of their grandparent `.mat-tree-node` do so

```
.mat-tree-node > .mat-icon-button {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: The second question is resolved, thank you! But the first one is still not work. Screenshot: https://image.ibb.co/ifvhvA/padding.png

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help(

Comment: i just added stackblitz to show you how to solve "reduce left offset problem"